# Silverlight and ATOM feeds that require authentication

Tags: c#, authentication, silverlight, webclient, atom-feed

I am building a simple feed reader application that needs to access an ATOM feed that requires authentication.  I was going down the route of using the WebClient class and found a Credential property that exists but is not implemented!

```
webclient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
```

Question:  What work around are people using for accessing feeds that require basic authentication from a Non-Microsoft site?

Answer (score 0):

You could make a proxy in javascript and have your silverlight controls interface with javascript, which in-turn does the HTTP fetching.
See this for an example: http://weblogs.asp.net/hpreishuber/archive/2009/07/30/silverlight-twitter-client-with-authentication.aspx